# how to see the rendering result of ascii doc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm newbie to ascii doc, I'm in a rush so I can't read the hole documentation. I used an existing ascii document to create my own, but I cannot see the result, I used asciidoctor, but still the document appears in chrome as simple text.

is there something that I'm missing ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see your documentation in Chrome, you need the [asciidoctorjs-live-preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia).

You need to configure the extension (context menu "Manage Extensions" on the "A" Button to open `chrome://extensions/`. Important is to select "Allow access to file URLs". Check also the "Options" link.) and activate it (click on the "A" button near the url box).

See also:

- https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-chrome-extension
- http://asciidoctor.org/news/2013/09/18/introducing-asciidoctor-js-live-preview/